# Calling superclasses with different syntax

Tags: python, kivy

A follow up to the question posted here: [Kivy/Python Countdown App project kivy has no attribute 'built' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36758038/kivy-python-countdown-app-project-kivy-has-no-attribute-built-error#)

From my understanding, we need to call the constructor (`__init__`) from the superclass so that the subclass can inherit and overwrite the superclass's function.

My question is why does `App.__init__(self)` works as shown in the solution but `super(Counter,self).__init__(**kwargs)` does not? I'm sure I'm missing something here

Comment: Why do you say `super(Counter,self).__init__(**kwargs)` doesn't work?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I got `name 'kwargs' is not defined` error

Comment: Oh, well of course, because it **isn't defined**. In this case, you would do `super(Counter, self).__init__()`, or just `super().__init__()`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ah yes... so `__init__(**kwargs)` would only work if I don't overwrite the function of the superclass?

Comment: No, it **has nothing to do with that**. `kwargs` is *not defined anywhere*. Why did you *expect* it to be? If you use `kwargs` in the scope, you will always get a `NameError`, because it isn't defined anywhere in that scope, just like if oyu did `banana`

Comment: Ah of course. noob question. Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga!